# Combinations to build a tower with different colored blocks

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, logic, permutations

**Ivan has 3 red blocks, 4 blue blocks and 2 green blocks.**

He builds the tower with randomly selected blocks but only stops when the tower consists of all three colours.

- **What is the probability that the tower is 4 blocks tall?**

---

My approach is the following but I am not sure at all:

to make it 3 colours it builds a tower that is either 3 blocks or 8 blocks.
8 blocks would happen in the case where the first 7 blocks are 4Blue and 3Red, so the 8th must be the green block.
so $E(8) = 4B,3R,1G = \binom{4}{4}*\binom{3}{3}*\binom{2}{1}= 2$

$E(7) = 4B,2G,1R = \binom{4}{4}*\binom{2}{2}*\binom{3}{1}= 3$

E(6) = let's reason the other way around. First $\binom{9}{6} = 84$. then the combinations of 6 blocks with only 2 colours is 4B,2R or 4B,2G  or  3B,3R.
This makes:

$ \binom{4}{4}*\binom{3}{2} + \binom{4}{4}*\binom{2}{2}+ \binom{4}{3}*\binom{3}{3}= 8$.

So $E(6) = 84 - 8 = 76$

E(5) = 3B,1R,1G  or  3R,1B,1G  or  2B,2R,1G  or  2B,2G,1R  or  2R,2G,1B =

$E(5) = \binom{4}{3}*\binom{3}{1}*\binom{2}{1}+ \binom{3}{3}*\binom{4}{1}*\binom{2}{1}+ \binom{4}{2}*\binom{3}{2}*\binom{2}{1}+ \binom{4}{2}*\binom{2}{2}*\binom{3}{1}+ \binom{3}{2}*\binom{2}{2}*\binom{4}{1}= 98$

E(4) = 2B,1R,1G  or  2R,1B,1G  or  2G,1B,1R =

$\binom{4}{2}*\binom{3}{1}*\binom{2}{1}+ \binom{3}{2}*\binom{4}{1}*\binom{2}{1}+ \binom{2}{2}*\binom{4}{1}*\binom{3}{1}= 72$

$E(3) = \binom{4}{1}*\binom{3}{1}*\binom{2}{1}= 24$

total combinations $(T) = 24 + 72 + 98 + 76 + 3 + 2 = 275$.

The probability of stopping at 4 blocks is $E(4)/(T) = 72/275$

but this is a very long solution. Do you think that is correct? if so, is there any other method to make it shorter?

Comment: So many questions, but where is the effort you have put in ? Can you let us know what you have tried ?

Comment: Your question has been downvoted and is about to be closed.  mathSE has an unusual protocol.  Going forward, with your future questions, if you wish to influence mathSE reviewers to react positively, rather than negatively, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Use MathJax when formatting your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Does $ncm$ mean $\binom{n}{m}$? Your question still needs a lot of improvement. Please learn how to use MathJax.

Comment: Hi @Gary. Yes it means that. I will modify it again and make it better. Sorry, I am new here. I am learning.